# excel udf not updating after listobj refresh

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel udf as one of the columns of a listobj (excel table).  When I refresh the table I get mixed results on whether the udf calculates or not. Some of the cells recaculate some return #value.  If I select a #value cell and click in the formula bar and click the 'check' it evaluates correctly.  Or if I copy it down the column it calculates correctly.
I've added a worksheet change event to .calculate the listobj.

Any advise is appreciated.

Here's my user defined function.

```
Function colorscore(dest, score)
```

`Dim scr`

```
scr = score
Select Case scr
Case Is = 99
    srcred = 255
    srcgreen = 0
    srcblue = 0
Case Is > 0
    srcred = (1 - scr) * 255
    srcgreen = 255 - ((255 - 176) * scr)
    srcblue = scr * 80
Case Else
    srcred = 255
    srcgreen = 255
    srcblue = 255
End Select
    dest.Parent.Evaluate "ChangeIt2(" & dest.Address(False, False) & "," _
                       & srcred & "," _
                       & srcgreen & "," _
                       & srcblue & "" _
                       & ")"
    colorscore = "Changed sheet!"                'or whatever return value is useful...
End Function

Sub ChangeIt2(c1 As Range, c2red, c2green, c2blue)
    c1.Interior.Color = RGB(c2red, c2green, c2blue)
End Sub
```

here's the worksheet change event

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.ListObject Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False
ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I took the liberty of indenting your code with [Rubberduck's SmartIndenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/Indentation) so that it's actually readable. Full disclosure, I'm a contributor to that project.

Comment: @YowE3K - No. When I indented that I had the 'Indent Case' setting wrong when I indented it and apparently missed when I fixed it manually. Ooops! Another good argument for automating it... Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have 2 definitions of score: one is a parameter to the udf and the other is a defined named score.
Then you evaluate the defined name using [score] notation.

So Excel does not know that there is a dependency on defined name score and so the UDF does not recalc when you change defined name score

Comment: Not sure I follow what you mean about the 'defined name' score.  I altered things a bit, removed the brackets, assigned the passed in UDF score parameter to a variable.  Still behaves as before though.  I've also added the code behind the worksheet change event.