# Highlighlight a Cell in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have this piece of VBA code;

```
Option Explicit

Function GradeScore(score As Integer) As String
    'Calculate grade based on the score given

    ThisWorkbook.Activate

    If score > 100 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Font.Background = rgbRed
        MsgBox "Score can not be more than 100%"
        Exit Function
    End If

    If score < 0 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Font.Background = rgbRed
        MsgBox "Score can not be less than 0%"
        Exit Function
    End If

    Select Case score
        Case Is >= 75
            GradeScore = "A"

        Case Is >= 70
            GradeScore = "B+"

        Case Is >= 60
            GradeScore = "B"

        Case Is >= 50
            GradeScore = "C"

        Case Is >= 45
            GradeScore = "D"

        Case Else
            GradeScore = "E"

    End Select

End Function
```

When run everything works except for the highlight cell code

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Font.Background = rgbRed
```

My guess is that it does not pick the cell referenced. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You want to be `font color` red or `cell background color` red?

Comment: @harun24hr, i want cell background color red, though neither the font changed in my previous run.

Comment: Are you using it as UDF to be called fro Excel UI oR as function to be called in a macro?

Comment: @user3598756, as UDF to be called from Excel UI.

Comment: Real quick, what if you do `Application.Caller.Offset(0,-1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4`?  And to be clear, you don't get an error, it's just that no cells are colored?  In any case, I don't think you want [font.background](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837850.aspx), but instead [cell.interior](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/background-colors.html)

Comment: @BruceWayne, calling Application.Caller.Offset(0, -1).Font.Background = rgbRed, does nothing. Yes I do not get an error just that the cell will the number is not highlighted as expected.

Comment: A UDF is not meant to be used to do anything other than return a value from the function to the `Application.Caller`.  It is fairly safe to use it to change the font, etc, of `Application.Caller`, but it can't (without using some unsupported hacks) be used to change the contents or formats of other cells.  Why don't you just use conditional formatting to change the colours of the cells you want (I assume they are the ones containing the scores) - that way you also don't have to worry about changing the colours back again once the error is fixed.

Comment: Similar:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42449795/excel-udf-not-updating-after-listobj-refresh

Comment: @TimWilliams - yep, that's the unsupported hack.  :D

Comment: @YowE3K I know - just in case the OP wants to try it.  But conditional formatting seems the obvious choice here

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Interior.Color = rgbRed
```